# Pass Dependency property through style in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to pass DependencyProperty itself through style.

Here is my dependency property inside my behaviour class

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundDependencyProperty =
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BoundDependency", typeof(DependencyProperty), typeof(TextboxBehaviour));
```

And i wanted to pass the `"TextBox.DataContextProperty"` from my style.

```
<Setter Property="TextboxBehaviour.BoundDependency" Value="???????"/>
```

will i be able to  pass the TextBox.DataContext property through my style ???

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Your attached property should be registered with type `object` (because that is the type of the `DataContext` property):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundDependencyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "BoundDependency",
        typeof(object), // here
        typeof(TextboxBehaviour));
```

Then you would set its value by a Binding in a Style Setter like this:

```
<Setter Property="TextboxBehaviour.BoundDependency"
    Value="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```